# Android: FC when querying sqlite opened database

Tags: android, sqlite, thread-safety

does the Android system automatically close an open SQLite Database? I've implemented a singleton class for accessing data and sometimes the methods there needs to be run on a worker thread. I have a synch functionality with queries that run on the background, here's the code:

```
public ArrayList<ActualCall> getUnsentCalls(boolean forUnsentSignature) {
    ArrayList<ActualCall> calls = new ArrayList<ActualCall>();

    Cursor c;
    open();

    if (forUnsentSignature)
        c = db.rawQuery("SELECT * FROM " + TXN_ACTUAL_CALL_COMPONENT
                + " WHERE sentFlag=1 and sigSentFlag=?", new String[] {"0"});
    else
        c = db.rawQuery("SELECT * FROM " + TXN_ACTUAL_CALL_COMPONENT
                + " WHERE sentFlag=? AND signature != ''", new String[] {"0"});

    if (c.moveToFirst()) {
        do {
            if (!db.isOpen())
                open();
            ActualCall call = new ActualCall();

            call.setAcpComponentId(c.getString(c.getColumnIndex("acpComponentId")));
            call.setAcpDate(c.getString(c.getColumnIndex("acpDate")));
            call.setAcpId(c.getString(c.getColumnIndex("acpId")));
            call.setCallEndTime(c.getString(c.getColumnIndex("callEndTime")));
            call.setCallStartTime(c.getString(c.getColumnIndex("callStartTime")));
            call.setCoordinates(c.getString(c.getColumnIndex("coordinates")));
            call.setDeviceTimestamp(c.getString(c.getColumnIndex("deviceTimestamp")));
            call.setDoctorId(c.getString(c.getColumnIndex("doctorId")));
            call.setSignature(c.getString(c.getColumnIndex("signature")));
            call.setSigSentFlag(c.getString(c.getColumnIndex("sigSentFlag")));
            call.setTimeSpent(c.getString(c.getColumnIndex("timeSpent")));
            call.setSentFlag(c.getString(c.getColumnIndex("sentFlag")));
            call.setCoordinates(c.getString(c.getColumnIndex("coordinates")));

            calls.add(call);

        } while (c.moveToNext());
    }

    c.close();
    db.close();

    return calls;
}
```

As you can see, I've already called open() on the initial lines yet I'm getting an error that tells that my database is already closed. Here's the stack trace:

```
 java.lang.IllegalStateException: database    
 /data/data/com.***.****/databases/****.db (conn# 0) already closed
 at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.verifyDbIsOpen(SQLiteDatabase.java:2123)
 at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.lock(SQLiteDatabase.java:398)
 at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.lock(SQLiteDatabase.java:390)
 at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteQuery.fillWindow(SQLiteQuery.java:74)
 at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteCursor.fillWindow(SQLiteCursor.java:311)
 at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteCursor.getCount(SQLiteCursor.java:292)
 at android.database.AbstractCursor.moveToPosition(AbstractCursor.java:156)
 at android.database.AbstractCursor.moveToFirst(AbstractCursor.java:233)
 at com.***.****.datalayer.ESCAndroidDataLayer.getUnsentCalls(ESCAndroidDataLayer.java:5340)
 at com.***.****.synchall.SynchAll$UnsentSignatureSender.run(SynchAll.java:1750)
```

Again, the method above is called on a Thread class, if that helps. I've found a link regarding SQLite being closed automatically but I don't understand his solution : http://darutk-oboegaki.blogspot.com/2011/03/sqlitedatabase-is-closed-automatically.html

Answer (score 0):

Try to call **db.acquireReference()** before c.moveToFirst()

```
    db.acquireReference();

    if (c.moveToFirst()) {
```

or it may be sufficient simply to enclose db.close() with "**if (db.isOpen())**".

```
    if (db.isOpen())
    {
        db.close();
    }
```

I'm not so sure but these will change something.

Comment: I have a location fetcher working on the background, it fetches a location then saves it to the DB. I am not sure though if this can affect my other database accesses if it coincidentally happens simultaneously.